# Testing automated tests in Hyper-V virtual machines

Tags: automated-testing, load-testing, virtualmachine

I recently started with a company which does not have any other full-time testers (testing as such is done primarily by people from support), so I don't have other people within the company to ask this kind of question.

Essentially, we are going to soon start running Hyper-V virtual machines to perform load testing of our software. I was wondering A) if anyone had any experience working with Hyper-V, and if so what kind of outside problems I should look for when running testing on that environment; and B) if there is a tool that will allow me to launch an automated test (for example, running AutoHotKey from one machine) over multiple virtual machines and log which machines the tests have failed or not?

Comment: The quick answer is: Yep, there are lots of tools out there for that. However, it will take a lot of setup, so be prepared to become an amateur sysadmin to make it all work.

Answer (score 2):

We are using Hyper-V to run our continuous integration server.  We are using MSTest.exe from Visual Studio 2010 with NCover and CruiseControl.NET.  The great thing about CruiseControl is that you can access it from a web browser.  Here are some links that I have found to be useful in setting it up:

http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/

and,

http://www.ncover.com/

Haven't had any major problems working with Hyper-V when using Windows 7.  Please feel free to let me know if you have any other questions, concerns or issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I'll take a look into the links you provided!